# Mapping county level disease outbreaks in the US, including Alaska, using R

Tags: r, mapping

I currently have county level data for amphibian disease outbreaks in the USA which includes events in Alaska. I used the package usmap, and got what I wanted for the lower 48 states but have to find a way to show the data for Alaska. I am not worried about missing Hawaii as it does not have the disease outbreaks I'm looking at anyway.

Does anyone know how I can show Alaska data, either using usmaps or another package you could recommend?

Additionally, I would like to do something similar for Canada. I have not acquired that data yet and will have to figure out how to spatially represent it since they do not have "counties". But if there is a package out there that could be helpful to me with all US states and Canadian provinces with county or equivalent level data, please let me know!

I tried downloading maps from urban mapr off github, which has county level data for the USA including ALaska,but am struggling with some things.

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("UrbanInstitute/urbnmapr")
```

For one, my disease data has a group number for each individual county, which is what I used to color in the county for my map. The urbanmapr does not. This causes a bit of trouble where certain county names occur in multiple states such as Carroll County, NH and Carroll County, Maryland, etc.

Here is the head of the data table (called na_rv_highlight_states_counties) I am using to plot my maps.

```
Counties (or equivalent)      long      lat group order region highlight Event ID Number Affected
1                aroostook -70.03263 46.56428  1145 35601  maine      TRUE    14750            3500
2                aroostook -70.03263 46.56428  1145 35601  maine      TRUE    13939              50
3                aroostook -70.03263 46.56428  1145 35601  maine      TRUE    13951              50
4                aroostook -70.03263 46.56428  1145 35601  maine      TRUE    13776             100
5                aroostook -70.02690 46.61584  1145 35602  maine      TRUE    14750            3500
6                aroostook -70.02690 46.61584  1145 35602  maine      TRUE    13939              50

  Event Start Date Event End Date States (or equivalent)                                          species
1         7/1/2003      9/12/2003                  Maine                Brook Trout; Bullfrog; Green Frog
2         7/7/1999       7/7/1999                  Maine                                        Wood Frog
3        7/23/1999      7/23/1999                  Maine                                        Wood Frog
4        7/20/1998      7/28/1998                  Maine Spotted Salamander; Unidentified Frog; Wood Frog
5         7/1/2003      9/12/2003                  Maine                Brook Trout; Bullfrog; Green Frog
6         7/7/1999       7/7/1999                  Maine                                        Wood Frog

  Event Diagnosis
1              Rv
2              Rv
3              Rv
4      Rv suspect
5              Rv
6              Rv
```

And this is the code that I have to make the map currently:

```
rv_map_hightlighted <- ggplot(rv_highlight_states_counties) +
  geom_polygon(data = na_rv_highlight_states_counties |>
                 arrange(order),
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = `Number Affected`),
               color = "gray40", linewidth = 0.3) +
  geom_polygon(data = us_state_map, 
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), 
               fill = NA, color = "black") + #NA for fill because it will overwrite the highlight color
  geom_polygon(data = us_states_counties,
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
               color = "gray80", fill = NA, linewidth = 0.01) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "darkgreen") +  
  
  
  coord_fixed(1.3) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Ranavirosis Mortality Events Detected from 1999 - 2023")
```

I am fairly new to R/programming so not sure if there is an easy fix to my code or data here that I am missing that someone could help with, or if I'm at a loss for finding the type of mapping package that I need.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks[image]